# I receive an error decimal.InvalidOperation when converting a currency

Tags: python, decimal, locale, currency

I receive an error when I try to convert a currency:

```
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]
```

My code:

```
import decimal
decimal.Decimal("$1,234.00")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting your currency from your appropriate locale. In case of a USD ($), the appropriate locale is `"USA"`:

```
import decimal
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'USA')
decimal.Decimal(locale.delocalize("$1,234.00").lstrip("$"))
```

As you can see, I've also manually removed the "$" sign.

If you prefer not to deal with localization, you may just remove the commas (`,`) like so:

```
decimal.Decimal("$1,234.00".replace(",","").lstrip("$"))
```